# Animation: hover over "image" and image particles move

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation

I'm trying to find out what this animation is called. On this website, when you hover over the pictures, they move in a motion. I want to try something like this. What is this called so I can find more information on it?
https://www.eugenius.com/#entrance

Comment: basically canvas drawing, it could be 3d we call webGL. you can do many things like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was made with the ThreeJS library, you cand find more information about it here
https://threejs.org/

Comment: Thanks, how did you know it was made from that library?

Comment: I recommend you this extension for chrome, Wappalyzer https://www.wappalyzer.com/, it allows you to check some of the libraries used in a webpage.

Comment: Hm interesting, it doesn't seem to list the libraries for the website for me, the extension gives me a captcha and a font script but nothing on ThreeJS

Comment: That's weird, to me it lists: reCAPTCHA Google Font API three.js Google Tag Manager jQuery3.2.1